# How to config spring security to use my customized UserDetailsManager?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security to manage user log in/signup in my project. I need to implement user lockout functionality after three failed log in attempts.What I did is to add another field 'account_non_locked' in 'Users' table in database.

The problem I'm facing is that spring security does not update that newly added column. I digged into the source code and found in the default UserDetailsManager the sql statement is written as:

```
"insert into users (username, password, enabled) values (?,?,?)"
```

which explains why it does not recognized my new column.

So I copy that file and change it to fit my own need, which is CustomUserDetailsManager.java

Now I can't configure spring security to use my own customized UserDetailsManager. The configuration file right now is:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    <jdbc-user-service id="userDetailsService" data-source-ref="dataSource" />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder" />
```

I can't find any examples online that will configure this properly. Please help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The section [3.2.4 Using other Authentication Providers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-auth-providers) covers how to do this using [authentication-provider@user-service-ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-authentication-provider-user-service-ref).

Your example would look something like the following:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsManager">
    <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" 
  class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder" />

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsManager"
  class="com.example.CustomUserDetailsManager">
  <!-- additional properties -->
</beans:bean>
```